# What's the difference between these 2 functions in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding

```
mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');

htmlentities($html);
```

What's the difference between the 2 functions above?

Comment: About the same as the difference between `split` and `explode`, I'd say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.net:

> mb_convert_encoding — Convert character encoding

This simply converts the passed string to the specified encoding type. In your example, this would be UTF-8. HTML passed to this will not be escaped. [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

> htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

This means that the string passed in will have all of the HTML tags escaped.

For example:

```
<b>This is some</b> <a href="http://php.net">HTML</a>
```

Will become

```
&lt;b&gt;This is some&lt;/b&gt; &lt;a href="http://php.net"&gt;HTML&lt;/a&gt;
```

when echoed to the screen, instead of being interpreted as HTML. [Link 2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)